# IOS Developer enterprise program apps distribution

Tags: ios

i couldn't find answers to the question anywhere, so because in stackOverflow I always get good answers for my coding problems from professional people, i would like to get help with these questions. I`m familiar with IOS developer program (99$) but I have two clients that ordered apps for iPhone and wish to distribute only inside their company, so i need to bye enterprise program (299$).

1. Do I need open 2 different enterprise accounts if i wish that firm A only can update and destitute her app?
2. How the company will distribute the app to their workers?
3. How the updating apps work, each company will use the own app store like option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use two separate accounts, one for each client, then the apps for both clients will exist in the same store.

When we develop for enterprise clients we request that they get their own Enterprise license.  A DUNS number is required for this process anyway.  Not just anybody can get an Enterprise license.

Comment: The company that i work in have DUNS number and the two other companies that ordered the applications have also DUNS number. Does your answer remains valid? I understand that each company will get their own app store like distribution, right?

Comment: Correct.  If our clients have DUNS numbers and they want an enterprise distribution we request that they setup their own enterprise account and we submit their apps to their enterprise account only.  Eventually , (probably sooner rather than later) some CIO, CTO, or IT manager is not going to like their "proprietary" apps mixed in with some other company's proprietary apps.  Companies are funny like that.